librdkafka error "Disconnected while requesting ApiVersion: might be caused by incorrect..." when producing
I've configured a Kafka broker in Docker from the bitnami/kafka image and can connect to it and produce/receive messages using plaintext security mode from both, a Kotlin (Java) client and a Python client. The Kotlin application and the Python script both work in all three use-cases: from a container in same compose, from an independent container, and from the same computer (Windows 11) but not containerised.
I need to integrate the Kafka producer in a C++ application so I integrated librdkafka.
Whenever I try to produce with a very simplistic producer in my C++ application, it always fails with error message Disconnected while requesting ApiVersion: might be caused by incorrect security.protocol configuration (connecting to a SSL listener?) or broker version is < 0.10 (see api.version.request).
Capturing the traffic with Wireshark I see a quite different behaviour when comparing librdkafka and the other two clients (Kotlin, Python). At creation of RD_KAFKA_PRODUCER it seems to be able to connect to the broker, requests for Kafka Metadata v12, receives the response, and changes state APIVERSION_QUERY -> UP. The log is below.
But when I try to produce a message things go a little weird, the client gets stuck in trying to obtain the same metadata and failing indefinitely.
My C++ application runs inside an Alpine Linux 3.19.0 container, I've tested by installing precompiled versions of librdkafka (version 2.5.0) and also tried downloading source code and build/install (version 2.5.0-2) with a ./configure activating options --enable-zlib --enable-zstd --enable-ssl --enable-gssapi --enable-curl --disable-lz4-ext.
I'm using same settings in all three applications: bootstrap.servers=192.168.1.106:9092, client.id=kfka-producer, security.protocol=PLAINTEXT.
What other(s) configuration setting(s) am I missing? What is the cause for this behaviour?
BR
Relevant log during publisher creation
%7|1724746409.258|CONNECT|kafka-producer-1#producer-1| [thrd:192.168.1.106:9092/bootstrap]: 192.168.1.106:9092/bootstrap: Connected to ipv4#192.168.1.106:9092
%7|1724746409.258|CONNECTED|kafka-producer-1#producer-1| [thrd:192.168.1.106:9092/bootstrap]: 192.168.1.106:9092/bootstrap: Connected (#1)
%7|1724746409.258|FEATURE|kafka-producer-1#producer-1| [thrd:192.168.1.106:9092/bootstrap]: 192.168.1.106:9092/bootstrap: Updated enabled protocol features +ApiVersion to ApiVersion
%7|1724746409.258|STATE|kafka-producer-1#producer-1| [thrd:192.168.1.106:9092/bootstrap]: 192.168.1.106:9092/bootstrap: Broker changed state CONNECT -> APIVERSION_QUERY
%7|1724746409.261|FEATURE|kafka-producer-1#producer-1| [thrd:192.168.1.106:9092/bootstrap]: 192.168.1.106:9092/bootstrap: Updated enabled protocol features to MsgVer1,ApiVersion,BrokerBalancedConsumer,ThrottleTime,Sasl,SaslHandshake,BrokerGroupCoordinator,LZ4,OffsetTime,MsgVer2,IdempotentProducer,ZSTD,SaslAuthReq
%7|1724746409.261|STATE|kafka-producer-1#producer-1| [thrd:192.168.1.106:9092/bootstrap]: 192.168.1.106:9092/bootstrap: Broker changed state APIVERSION_QUERY -> UP
%7|1724746409.263|BROKER|kafka-producer-1#producer-1| [thrd:main]: 127.0.0.1:9092/1: Added new broker with NodeId 1
%7|1724746409.263|CLUSTERID|kafka-producer-1#producer-1| [thrd:main]: 192.168.1.106:9092/bootstrap: ClusterId update "" -> "RzgGhnlKRPOQXG-JIwto6g"
%7|1724746409.263|CONTROLLERID|kafka-producer-1#producer-1| [thrd:main]: 192.168.1.106:9092/bootstrap: ControllerId update -1 -> 1
%7|1724746409.263|BRKMAIN|kafka-producer-1#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/1]: 127.0.0.1:9092/1: Enter main broker thread

Relevant log after trying to produce a message
%7|1724746594.290|STATE|kafka-producer-1#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/1]: 127.0.0.1:9092/1: Broker changed state INIT -> TRY_CONNECT
%7|1724746594.290|CONNECT|kafka-producer-1#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/1]: 127.0.0.1:9092/1: broker in state TRY_CONNECT connecting
%7|1724746594.290|STATE|kafka-producer-1#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/1]: 127.0.0.1:9092/1: Broker changed state TRY_CONNECT -> CONNECT
%7|1724746594.290|CONNECT|kafka-producer-1#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/1]: 127.0.0.1:9092/1: Connecting to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 (plaintext) with socket 17
%7|1724746594.290|TOPPAR|kafka-producer-1#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/1]: 127.0.0.1:9092/1: transactional-registers [0] 1 message(s) queued but broker not up
%7|1724746594.290|CONNECT|kafka-producer-1#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/1]: 127.0.0.1:9092/1: Connected to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092
%7|1724746594.290|CONNECTED|kafka-producer-1#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/1]: 127.0.0.1:9092/1: Connected (#1)
%7|1724746594.290|FEATURE|kafka-producer-1#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/1]: 127.0.0.1:9092/1: Updated enabled protocol features +ApiVersion to ApiVersion
%7|1724746594.290|STATE|kafka-producer-1#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/1]: 127.0.0.1:9092/1: Broker changed state CONNECT -> APIVERSION_QUERY
%7|1724746594.290|TOPPAR|kafka-producer-1#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/1]: 127.0.0.1:9092/1: transactional-registers [0] 1 message(s) queued but broker not up
%7|1724746594.290|TOPPAR|kafka-producer-1#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/1]: 127.0.0.1:9092/1: transactional-registers [0] 1 message(s) queued but broker not up
%7|1724746594.291|FAIL|kafka-producer-1#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/1]: 127.0.0.1:9092/1: Disconnected while requesting ApiVersion: might be caused by incorrect security.protocol configuration (connecting to a SSL listener?) or broker version is < 0.10 (see api.version.request) (after 1ms in state APIVERSION_QUERY) (_TRANSPORT)
%6|1724746594.291|FAIL|kafka-producer-1#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/1]: 127.0.0.1:9092/1: Disconnected while requesting ApiVersion: might be caused by incorrect security.protocol configuration (connecting to a SSL listener?) or broker version is < 0.10 (see api.version.request) (after 1ms in state APIVERSION_QUERY)
%7|1724746594.291|FEATURE|kafka-producer-1#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/1]: 127.0.0.1:9092/1: Updated enabled protocol features -ApiVersion to 
%7|1724746594.292|STATE|kafka-producer-1#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/1]: 127.0.0.1:9092/1: Broker changed state APIVERSION_QUERY -> DOWN
%7|1724746594.292|STATE|kafka-producer-1#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/1]: 127.0.0.1:9092/1: Broker changed state DOWN -> INIT
%7|1724746594.292|STATE|kafka-producer-1#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/1]: 127.0.0.1:9092/1: Broker changed state INIT -> TRY_CONNECT
%7|1724746594.292|RECONNECT|kafka-producer-1#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/1]: 127.0.0.1:9092/1: Delaying next reconnect by 274ms

Client creation code
// Configuration
rd_kafka_conf_t *kafka_conf = rd_kafka_conf_new();
// Parameters are copied from a YAML file:
// bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
// security.protocol=PLAINTEXT
// log_level=7
// api.version.request=true

// Producer
producer = rd_kafka_new(RD_KAFKA_PRODUCER, kafka_conf, errstr, sizeof(errstr));

// Messages are sent to the queue using:
err = rd_kafka_producev(
    producer,
    RD_KAFKA_V_TOPIC(topic_name),
    RD_KAFKA_V_MSGFLAGS(RD_KAFKA_MSG_F_COPY),
    RD_KAFKA_V_VALUE((void *) message_content.c_str(), message_content.size()),
    RD_KAFKA_V_OPAQUE(NULL),
    RD_KAFKA_V_END);

